# create empty object (empty brackets) with toJSON

Tags: json, r, rjson

I need to create a JSON string from R using `toJSON`. My issue is that part of the JSON should contain an empty JSON object `{}`. I thought `list()` would do it for me:

```
> fromJSON("{}")
list()
> toJSON(list())
[1] "[]"
```

[Scratches head]

Anybody know how to get a `{}` using `toJSON`? I am using a lib that does the encoding, so answers that do not use `toJSON` will not help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of packages that have `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions.

Using `rjson::fromJSON`, `'{}'` is read in as a `list` of length `0`, whereas `RJSONIO::fromJSON` reads in `{}` as a `named list` of length 0.

In either package, calling `fromJSON` on a named list will do what you want.

Clearly, `RJSONIO` is performing as you want it to do

```
RJSONIO::toJSON(RJSONIO::fromJSON('{}'))
## [1] '{}'

rjson::toJSON(rjson::fromJSON('{}'))
## [1] "[]"
```

If you use `rjson` then you will have to manually set the `names` of the list of length `0`

```
rjson::toJSON(setNames(rjson::fromJSON('{}'), character(0)))
## [1] "{}"
```